# Strategy Pattern with Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In one of my angular projects I keep find cases where I want to use a strategy pattern, but with directives as the strategies. Examples include widgets on a configurable dashboard (where the 'strategy' is each widget that's being displayed), or a form where the user specifies a type of request and the entire form implementation swaps out (where each 'strategy' in this case is an implementation for a specific type of form, I appreciate this may be considered a use case for a URL route but that's not always appropriate).

Looking at the problem I can see 2 possible ways to go about this. The first being ng-include, where each 'widget' or where the form is just an ng-include, and we swap out the template URL to pull in the different implementations. The second being a 'proxy' directive that instantiates the real directive inside, something like this where you pass the desired directive as an attribute.

```
angular.module("test", []).directive("directiveProxy", function($compile){
  function link(scope, elem, attrs){
    var update = function(){
      var elem1 = $compile("<" + scope.tag + "></" + scope.tag + ">");
      var elem2 = angular.element(elem1(scope));
      elem.empty().append(elem2);
    };
    scope.$watch('tag', update);
    update();
  }

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      content: "=",
      tag: "="
    },
    link: link
  };
})
```

Which could be used as simply as:

```
<directive-proxy tag="real-angular-component"></directive-proxy>
```

The former pattern has the advantage of being relatively simple, though difficult to pass any sort of arguments into, while the latter seems to allow arguments but puts another directive in the way as well as requiring the proxy to be tailored to each set of arguments that need to be passed.

Is there a third option for doing this type of directive-swapping-out that I've missed? Are there any significant advantages to either of these approaches that mean they're the way it should be done?

Comment: It depends on what exactly is your case. For dynamic 'tag' it's as you described. For static 'tag' `template` function is preferable.